# Using YAML in GAE environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

GAE uses PyYAML to deal with YAML files. I see that library in GAE Python SDK in lib folder inside GAE SDK folder. I copied it into my app project and imported its modules. It's all working fine on my local PC. Is that possible to use PyYAML from GAE environment without having to have a copy of it in my application? If it's available in GAE on the server, then I suppose there is an access to this library. How to properly import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the website, [PyYAML 3.05 is included](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#YAML):

> The App Engine Python SDK uses YAML as the format for its configuration files. The environment provides the YAML parsing libraries for Python, PyYAML 3.05.

I expect you can just include it the normal way:

```
>>> import yaml
```